# Netbeans project Linux deployment

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, deployment

I've created a Java app in linux using NetBeans 7.2. Building the project it creates the .jar file, but now I need to deploy it on several PC's.

I would like to create an executable file with a desktop shortcup icon. How do I do this??

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/index.html) (in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html)).

Comment: executeable as in jar file? If so just do "java -jar path-to-jar.jar" you can create a new shortcut on the desktop with those parameters

Comment: my app has a jframe as the entry point, I've tried "java -jar path-to-jar.jar" and nothing happens